# How do I search through a sheet of data and return MULTIPLE matching results on another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my desired flow:

1. On "Sheet2" you can select a macro "Search by first name"
2. You see a popup to enter a name, you enter a name (X) and select ok
3. It will search the next sheet, "Master", and look for results where first name = X
4. and finally return these results back on "Sheet2"

Here's a screenshot of the two sheets:

Sheet 2

[image: Sheet2] and

Master

[image: Master]

The following VB code means that it only returns 1 result when there should be multiple sometimes:

```
Sub Searchbyfirstname()

Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rCell As Excel.Range
Dim fFirst As String

Dim i As Long

Dim MyVal As String
MyVal = InputBox("Enter the first name of the employees record you need", "Search By First Name", "")

If MyVal = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Cells(5, 1)
    .Value = "The below data has been found for " & MyVal & ":"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
i = 2

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If wks.Name <> "List" Then

        With wks.Range("B:B")

            Set rCell = .Find(MyVal, , , xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
            If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
                fFirst = rCell.Address
                Do
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(6, 1), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address
                    wks.Range("A" & rCell.Row & ":Z" & rCell.Row).Copy Destination:=Cells(6, 1)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 3 
                Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing And rCell.Address <> fFirst
            End If
        End With
     End If

Next wks

Set rCell = Nothing

If i = 2 Then
    MsgBox "No record for " & MyVal & " has been found", 64, "No Matches"
    Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi - can you please remove all the comments. Its cloggin up the code making it unreadable.

Comment: Okay - so when you are hyperlinking, you are hard-coding. So even if you find multiple names, the names are still being hyperlinked to same location. You need to increment the hyperlink path. Basically what will be displayed is the last item that was found. Sorry - I am reading this on phone. With all the comments in code, its very difficult to separate the code from comments and I could be wrong.

Comment: In addition to Maertins comment, your copy is also copying to the same destination each time ( `... .Copy Destination:=Cells(6, 1)` ) and copying to the Active Sheet which may or may not be Sheet2

Comment: Sorry guys, I have removed the comments now does this make it any clearer to read? Would you know how to increment the hyperlink path or increment the copy destination?

Comment: I am thinking a For loop and instead of having 6 there it is a variable e.g. x and I can increment x by 1 until there are no more entries to add. But not sure how to do this.

Comment: I think I've done it so I've left an answer on this

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I am pretty sure I have the answer now that Maertin and chris neilsen pointed out the errors with hardcoding.

I have posted my code again but the points where I have added or changed are not code (didn't know the best way to format this):

```
Sub Searchbyfirstname()

Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rCell As Excel.Range
Dim fFirst As String

Dim i As Long

Dim MyVal As String
MyVal = InputBox("Enter the first name of the employees record you need",         "Search By First Name", "")

If MyVal = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Cells(5, 1)
.Value = "The below data has been found for " & MyVal & ":"
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
i = 2

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 If wks.Name <> "List" Then

    With wks.Range("B:B")

        Set rCell = .Find(MyVal, , , xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)

        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then

            fFirst = rCell.Address
```

Dim x As Integer

x = 6

With Sheets("Sheet2")

.Rows(6 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete

End With

' for this part I have created the variable x, then I'm assigning this 6 because that's the first row I want to put the data in, then I am saying if there's anything in row 6 or below, delete it

```
            Do

rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(x, 1), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address
```

'see this and row below, instead of being Cells(6, 1), it is now x and this means it will paste to 6, then if there's another 7 and so on

```
                wks.Range("A" & rCell.Row & ":Z" & rCell.Row).Copy Destination:=Cells(x, 1)

                Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                i = i + 3
```

x = x + 1

' Here I am incrementing x by 1 so that if there's another piece of data to paste it will paste in the next row - on first go this would be row 7

```
            Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing And rCell.Address <> fFirst
        End If
    End With
 End If 

Next wks

Set rCell = Nothing

If i = 2 Then
MsgBox "No record for " & MyVal & " has been found", 64, "No Matches"
Cells(1, 1).Value = ""

With Sheets("Sheet2")
.Rows(5 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```